# error laravel variable in a query to check date

Tags: laravel

i try since 2 days to create a query to select the right `categorieAgerange` depend on the `$variable = dt_naissance`

first i have two tables :  `licencie(id , ... , catg_licence_id)`

`catg_licence(id , lb_name , nb_age_min , nb_age_max)`

here my function store :

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {

    $licencie = new Licencie;
    $licencie->club_id = $request->input('club_id');
    $licencie->structure_id = $request->input('structure_id');
    $licencie->dt_naissance = $request->input('dt_naissance');
    $licencie->pays_naissance_id = $request->pays_naissance_id;

    //here i check the age of the licence 
    $dt_naissance = Carbon::parse($request->dt_naissance)->diff(Carbon::now())->format('%y');

dd($dt_naissance) -> i get the good age like "2" for two years for people who select 2014 for exemple
```

then i would like to make a between query to select the propor `catg_licence_id` to my licence and inject to my database

i tried this :

```
$catg_licence_id = CatgLicence::whereBetween($dt_naissance , ['nb_age_min' , 'nb_age_max'])->firstOrFail()->id;
```

but i get an error : 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '22' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `id` from `catg_licence` where (`22` between nb_age_min and nb_age_max))

someone have an idea how i can resolve the problem ? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`whereBetween` takes the column as the first parameter.

```
->whereBetween('age', [1, 100])->get();
```

But in your case you might want to try

```
CatgLicence::where('nb_age_min', '<', $dt_naissance)
->where('nb_age_max', '>', $dt_naissance)
->first();
```

Try that one and see how it goes. 
Bonne chance!

Comment: OK i fixed ! sometimes i have small range values link nb_age_min =5 and nb_max_age = 6 , i did your solution CatgLicence::where('nb_age_min', '<=', $dt_naissance)
->where('nb_age_max', '>=', $dt_naissance)
->first(); ! it's working thanks so much !!!!!!!

Comment: J'ai pas bien compris ce que t'as dit plus haut.

Comment: It's working fine. Perhaps you should mark my answer :)

Comment: i just have problem now to instert the id of the categorie to my licencie table ! i tried   $licencie->catg_licence_id=$categorie_age->id; i get also the $dt_naissance i would like to get only the id of the categorie to insert

Comment: After assigning like that, you can save with `$licence->save();` or `$licence->update();`

Comment: my fault sorry i changed firstOrFail()->id instead of first() now i get the right object with the id to insert ! many thanks once again man , you saved my day !!!!!!! ;)